# Disable option from dropdown when option is selected x times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown menu in form that calculates how many times option has been selected. I want to disable option when option has been selected x times. This is my code (nth iteration. I suck at coding.) that disables every option.

```
var x = 10
var time_1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("time-1").value)
var time_2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("time-2").value)
var time_3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("time-3").value)

$("#id").children().each(function() {
     if (time_1 >= x) {
         $(this).prop("disabled", "true");
     }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "selected `x` times"? Also you should use `const` and `let` instead of `var`.

Comment: In my example x = 10. if for example time_1 >= 10(option has been selected 10 times) then options should be disabled from dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good nights sleep and a cup of good coffee I managed to find a solution. I know this is not pretty code but it works for me. I might have been a bit obscure about what I was aiming for. Sorry about that.

```
$(function (){
var x = 10
var time_1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("time-1").value)
var time_2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("time-2").value)
var time_3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("time-3").value)

if (time_1 > x) { $('#id option[value="Option value 1"]').attr('disabled','disabled'); } 
if (time_2 > x) { $('#id option[value="Option value 2"]').attr('disabled','disabled'); }
if (time_3 > x) { $('#id option[value="Option value 3"]').attr('disabled','disabled'); } 
});
```